# Blocked on leads report

Tags: reporting, leads, joined-reports, report-chart

I’m having some trouble completing my client’s request. I was asked to create a report on leads grouped by the name of user who created the leads, with 3 columns:

1. record count of all leads
2. record count of leads in status A
3. % of all records that are in Status A

Client wants to see this report in a dashboard, preferably in table format with the same columns.

I have tried creating a joined report grouped by “Created By”, with 2 blocks (both blocks pertain to Leads). I  did not add a filter on the first block, but I added a filter on the 2nd block so it will only show the leads in Status A. I disabled the detailed rows so now I have the columns: Created by (grouping), Record count of all leads, Record count of leads in Status A.

What I’m blocked on:

1. How to get the %
2. How do I show the same report in a dashboard? I added a chart to the report (since salesforce doesn’t allow adding a joined report to dashboards unless the report has a chart). However, table format is not available on the chart so I used a bar graph, which consequently appeared as the format of the dashboard component.

Please help, I would appreciate it so much. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To get the percentage calculation you're looking at a [Summary Formula](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.building_custom_summary_formulas.htm&type=5). These operate across the groups within your report. The [Use Summary Formulas in Your Reports](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/create-reports-and-dashboards-for-sales-and-marketing-managers/use-summary-formulas-in-your-reports) trail has an example that will be useful for you in this scenario.

To show this information in a Dashboard, you should be able to just use a Table Dashboard Component with those columns.